# Getting a 404 when accessing spring boot app via nginx reverse proxy

Tags: spring-boot, nginx, reverse-proxy

I have a spring boot application running on my local mac on port 9096.

When I hit:

```
http://localhost:9096/murtaza
```

I get the desired response string 'murtaza'.

Now, when I am trying to configure a reverse proxy using nginx, I keep on getting a 404 error. Here is my nginx.conf file:

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
   worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
  include       mime.types;
  default_type  application/octet-stream;

#log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
#                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
#                 '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

#access_log  logs/access.log  main;

sendfile        on;
#tcp_nopush     on;

#keepalive_timeout  0;
keepalive_timeout  65;

#gzip  on;

server {
    listen       9070;
    server_name  localhost;

    #charset koi8-r;

    #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        root   html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    location = /murtaza {
       proxy_pass http://localhost:9096/murtaza; 
    }

    #error_page  404              /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   html;
    }

}
include servers/*;
```

}

The url I am hitting is

`http://localhost:9070/murtaza`

Answer (score 0):

So, the configuration are perfect. Doing a,

```
brew services info nginx
```

revealed that my nginx was `loaded` but not `running`. Had to reboot host and allow nginx from the firewall and then restart using,

```
brew services start nginx
```

to make things work.